# Select a random value out of a combo box using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, combobox, automation, webdriver

How can I select a random value out of a combo box using Selenium Webdriver?

Lets say this is may code below:

```
WebElement comboBox;
comboBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sponsorship_id']"));
```

Comment: Hi @Tunaki, thanks for your response, I saw this earlier but I cant get to make the code work 

WebElement comboBox;
comboBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sponsorship_id']"));
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(new Random().nextInt(comboBox.getSelectOptions()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement comboBoxElemenet;
comboBoxElemenet = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sponsorship_id']"));
Select comboBox= new Select(comboBoxElemenet );
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(comboBox.getOptions().size);
comboBox.selectByIndex(randomIndex);
```

Comment: thank you, the code is working perferctly